# PowerApps Filtering or Searching on LookUp field on Gallery

Tags: filter, delegates, powerapps

I am working on a Sold Items table which has ProductIds, which gets the names from "Products" using the ProductIds.

On my powerapp gallery; 
I use this statement to properly display data;

```
LookUp('[Products]',Item_Id = ThisItem.Item_Id,Retail_Name)
```

which is displayed on Title1.Text

on my gallery form, I use the filter

```
Filter('[Sold_Items]',Week_Id=Value(TextInputWeekId.Text))
```

I want to also add the search option, so that I can search;

```
inputSearchBox.Text = Title1.Text or use the LookUp function over ( Retail_Name )
```

No Matter what I have tried, I couldn't make this work.

Comment: This is quite unclear or hard to understand. You want to give some sample data & expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you have 2 tables, "Products" and "Sold_Items".
Your gallery receives the items from "Sold_Items", and you show the item name using:
`LookUp('[Products]',Item_Id = ThisItem.Item_Id,Retail_Name)` in the text property of a label that shows the product name.

You filter the gallery to show only the "Sold_Items" of the current week with the following code:
`Filter('[Sold_Items]',Week_Id=Value(TextInputWeekId.Text))` in the items property of the gallery.

Now you want to filter the items further more using a text input. Correct me if I'm wrong.

To accomplish this you will need to modify the `Items` property of your gallery. Your text-input label from where you want to filter the gallery has the name "inputSearchBox".

So, the Items property of your gallery should be:
`Filter('[Sold_Items]',Week_Id=Value(TextInputWeekId.Text) && Title1.Text = inputSearchBox.Text)`

Let me know if this is what you wanted and if it solved your problem.

Best Regards